# Error al usar MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Estoy intentando usar la librería MPDF para generar un PDF, pero usando la configuración de inicio que dan en la web oficial me arroja el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable in /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/ServiceFactory.php(56): Mpdf\Cache->__construct() #1 /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1066): Mpdf\ServiceFactory->getServices() #2 /var/www/html/nes_servidor/compras/os/pdf/generar_pdf.php(6): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php on line 21

Codigo:

```
<?php
error_reporting();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Create an instance of the class:
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

// Write some HTML code:
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

// Output a PDF file directly to the browser
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: cual es el contenido de **var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/** ??; de casualidad copiaste y pegaste el proyecto???

Comment: O posiblemente el usuario que corre ese Apache donde está PHP, no tiene permiso para ese directorio y debe poder crear archivos.

Comment: No copie el proyecto, instale directamente la librería con composer, debe ser por temas de permisos, como puedo validar si el usuario de apache tiene permisos para crear archivos en ese directorio? ando en un entorno con ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en inglés y dice

> Fatal error: Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Temporary files directory "/var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable in /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php

En resumen su traducción sería:

> Directorio de archivos temporales "ruta/al/directorio" no es escribible

Tu sistema operativo veo que es un Linux así que te recomendaría verificar los permisos de escritura y lectura en el siguiente orden:

1. Verificar que usuario esta usando tu Apache, normalmente puede usar el usuario **apache** o el usuario **www** lo podrías verificar ejecutando el comando `ps aux` para ver quien esta ejecutando el proceso httpd.
2. Verificar que tus carpetas tengan el usuario que encontraste en el paso anterior. El comando sería el siguiente:

   ```
   [user@host]~ ls -l /var/www/html/nes_servidor/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/
   total 12345
   drwxr-xr-x 1 user group        0 jun.  2 04:25  mpdf/
   ```
3. Donde dice *user* debería de decir apache o www, el nombre del usuario del servidor Apache, también tienes que verificar los permisos de escritura y lectura de la carpeta donde se planea escribir, la parte de drwxr-xr-x. El comando sería el mismo que el anterior pero checando la parte donde esta la parte de permisos.
4. Si todos esos están bien, tienes que buscar si el que esta bloqueando la escritura es SELinux, la forma más rápida para saberlo es deshabilitandolo con el comando `setenforce 0` probar, y si ya funciona configurar correctamente el SELinux para que lo permita, recordar regresar el setenforce a 1.